# Brand new to Mongo/Node/Meteor, wondering why Meteor isn't getting any data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm trying to run the `leaderboard` example, and I've inserted into `db.players`. However, when running `leaderboard`, no names appear. Not even the ones specified manually in the code. `mongod` is running.

Comment: I think people will need more details in order to help you troubleshoot. What exact commands have you used to insert? How are you sure the insert has been successful? If you use the inspector and run Players.find().forEach(function(p) {console.log(p)}) what do you see?

Comment: @lashleigh interesting. I do see the player names. However, they are not showing up on the document itself. http://i.imgur.com/H5wOX.png

Comment: Ok, cool clearly the players are in the database. If you paste in your leaderboard.js and leaderboard.html I'd be happy to help you look for the bug.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2395604

Comment: I copied your files into a fresh leaderboard project of my own and it works great. For some reason I assumed the problem would be in an edit - but did you make any edits to the project? If you deploy the project does it work in production mode? When you start the meteor server what does it do?

Comment: @lashleigh no edits whatsoever. It simply says `[[[Meteor running]]]`. No errors or anything of the sort. It's very strange - I haven't tried deploying.

Comment: Very strange, but without an error message to go on I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you're inserting into `db.players`, instead of `Players`
(`Players` is defined as a meteor collection at the top of leaderboard.js)

If that's the case, change your insert statement from:

```
db.players.insert...
```

to

```
Players.insert...
```